# When to use ::query in Laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel

I can use `User::where()` and `User::query()->where()`

With a `query` I get hints in IDE. But are there any other benefits or guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no benefit other than the IDE recognizing the initiation of a query builder instance.

As there is no benefits in not using it, since doing `User::where()` will call the [magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters) //$method = "where"
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

Which calls the magic method

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
public function __call($method, $parameters) //$method = "where"
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    if ($resolver = (static::$relationResolvers[get_class($this)][$method] ?? null)) {
        return $resolver($this);
    }

    return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters); //<---- and will end in here
}
```

While `User::query()` is

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
public static function query()
{
    return (new static)->newQuery();
}
```

So using `User::query()` helps the IDE and leads to less steps but basicly it's the same thing. (performance difference between both methods is negligible in our times)